# PyGame making grid by appending squares

Tags: python, pygame, grid

I am trying to understand how python and pygame works
So ,I am trying go build this square grid from: 
http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=en&chapter=array_backed_grids#step_07
Managed to do the row with 10 squares, but somehow i stuck on the part that i have to do the actual grid by creating another for loop and get this result

[image]

my code looks like this:

> ```
> import pygame
> pygame.init()
>
> win = pygame.display.set_mode((728, 728))
> tile_width = 64
> tile_height = 64
> margin = 8  # space between the boxes
> white = (255, 255, 255)
>
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
>
> run = True
> while run:
>     for event in pygame.event.get():
>         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>             run = False
>
>     x, y = margin, margin
>     for column in range(10):
>         for row in range(0, column):
>             rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, tile_width, tile_height)
>             pygame.draw.rect(win, white, rect)
>             x = x + tile_width + margin
>             y = y + tile_width + margin
>
>     pygame.display.update()
>
> pygame.quit()
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset `y` before the inner loop and you have to increment `x` after the inner loop rather than in the inner loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    x = margin
    for column in range(10):
        y = margin
        for row in range(10):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, tile_width, tile_height)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, rect)
            y = y + tile_height + margin
        x = x + tile_width + margin

    pygame.display.update()
```

Alternatively you can compute `x` and `y` in the loop, dependent on `row` and `column`:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    for column in range(10):
        x = margin + column * (tile_height + margin)
        for row in range(10):
            y = margin + row * (tile_width + margin) 
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, tile_width, tile_height)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white, rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```